# PHP: Array_unshift an not numeric index

Tags: php, arrays

Just wanted to add a new parameter in the front of my array with array_unshift, but: If I do it like usual, it has an numeric index. How can I decline the index, e.g. something like that...

```
<?php
$queue = array("a", "B");
array_unshift($queue, "front" => "hello" ); //Not working, this is my question ;)
?>
```

The array would then look like

```
Array {
    front => hello
    0 => a
    1 => B
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like array_unshift cannot do what you want. Try this:

```
$queue = array('a', 'B');
$queue = array_merge(array('front' => 'hello'), $queue);
```

This gives the result you want.

```
Array
(
    [front] => hello
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

Answer (score 11):

`array_push`, `array_pop`, `array_shift`, `array_unshift` are designed for numeric arrays.

You can use one of the `array_merge` solutions some people already mentioned or you can use the `+` operator for arrays:

```
$queue = array('front' => 'Hello') + $queue;
```

*Note: When using `array_merge` the items with the same keys from the second array will overwrite the ones from the first one, so if 'front' already exists in `$queue` it will not be overwritten, but only brought to the front. On the other hand if you use `+`, the new value will be present in the result and be at the front.*

Comment: +1 for being the answer that will work correctly if there is already a `front` item in the array.

Comment: @salathe Thank you. But I'm not sure which of the two option (+ or array_merge) the asker really needs. I'll add a note to make him aware of the difference.

Comment: with both options the item will be at the start of the array, the difference is the value it has. The question makes it clear what value Florian is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$new_queue = array_merge(array("front"=>"hello"), $queue);
```

The reason why you must use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and not [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) is because the latter only works on numerically indexed arrays.

Comment: Yeah i know, but how can i add with array_unshift an element with a string as index?

Comment: You can't.  array_unshift only works with numeric arrays.  What's wrong with array_merge?