# PHP - add item to beginning of associative array

Tags: php

How can I add an item to the beginning of an associative array?  For example, say I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
```

When I add something to it as in `$arr['key0'] = 'value0';`, I get:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [key1] => value1
>     [key2] => value2
>     [key0] => value0
> )
> ```

How do I make that to be

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [key0] => value0
>     [key1] => value1
>     [key2] => value2
> )
> ```

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Note that [minimal code samples](https://sscce.org/) are much more helpful than variable dumps alone (though the latter can also be helpful).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP prepend associative array with literal keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371016/php-prepend-associative-array-with-literal-keys). See also: [PHP: Array_unshift an not numeric index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516664/php-array-unshift-an-not-numeric-index).

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You could use the [*union* operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$arr1 = array('key0' => 'value0') + $arr1;
```

or [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: Which is more efficient? union or array_merge? If I may ask...

Comment: @melvin: Perhaps you could do a performance test and tell us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure union is faster.

Comment: and `array_merge` didn't work with this: `$years = array_merge(array('2014'=>'2014'),$years);` for some reason, while the union operator did work.

Comment: @Timo Huovinen, array_merge didn't work because PHP converted your key to a number, and array_merge resets numeric keys.

Comment: @toby: `array_merge` does work with non-numeric keys, and the documentation actually explains what happens to numeric keys: *"Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array."*

Comment: @FelixKling: How did I not know about this union operator? Amazing. This is great!

Comment: I don't know why, but in a forloop overwriting the same array (in this answer `$arr1`) with this technique ended me up with an array with only one item. `array_merge` did work however.

Comment: +1 for this brilliant trick! Was able to sort a multidimensional array and then prepend the array. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 23):

One way is with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
<?php
$arr = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
$arr = array_merge(array('key0' => 'value0'), $arr);
```

Depending on circumstances, you may also make use of [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort).

Comment: It doesn't matter in this instance, but if an element with key `'key0'` already existed in `$arr` then this _value_ would overwrite the new value being prepended (ie. `'value0'` would get overwritten). You can use the [union operator (`+`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to resolve this.

Answer (score 7):

```
$array = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
array_combine(array_unshift(array_keys($array),'key0'),array_unshift(array_values($array),'value0'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function unshift( array & $array, $key, $val)
{
    $array = array_reverse($array, 1);
    $array[$key] = $val;
    $array = array_reverse($array, 1);

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to merge the arrays you could just use `ksort()` on the array before iterating over it.