# Associative array - move an element to first position

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - add item to beginning of associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783750/php-add-item-to-beginning-of-associative-array)

have associative array:

```
$myarray=array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2");
```

Need to add a new element to array:

```
$myarray["keynew"]="valuenew";
```

So now $myarray is:

```
Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 [keynew] => valuenew )
```

How can I move the new added element ("keynew"=>"valuenew") to the first position of the array?

I have an workaround, but I don't like it.

```
$myarray=array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2");
$myarray["keynew"]="-valuenew";
asort($myarray);
$myarray["keynew"]="valuenew";
//$myarray=Array ( [keynew] => valuenew [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$myArray  = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
$myArray2 = array('keynew' => 'valuenew');
var_dump($myArray2 + $myArray);
```

Output:

```
% php test.php 
array(3) {
  ["keynew"]=>
  string(8) "valuenew"
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `array_merge()` function - it merges arrays while preserving order.

```
<?php
$myarray = array_merge(array('keynew' => '-valuenew'), $myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into array_merge yet?  I think that would help you out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php