# Associative array move last element to first

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array(
'key1'=>'value1',
'key2'=>'value2',
'key3'=>'value3'
)
```

I want create it like

```
array(
'key3'=>'value3',
'key1'=>'value1',
'key2'=>'value2'
)
```

I just want to move the last element to first with key value pair keeping all other details as it is.

Comment: Neither you nor your code should know or care about what order an associative array's keys are in - often it is unspecified, and it doesn't matter anyway. If you care about order, use a numeric array.

Comment: No its not a numeric array.

Comment: It is an associative array.
Actual this is not my real array.

Comment: The real array is very big so I just entered a sample.
Anyways I got my answer from the below mentioned post.

Comment: `$firstAsLast = array_merge(array_splice($array, 1), $array);` or `$lastAsFirst = array_merge(array_splice($array,-1), $array);`

Comment: This should be reopened IMO, but I lack the rep to do so. The close reason provided is absurd - this is extremely clear and answerable. This *does* matter in some cases: consider an array of 50 states (`'AK' => 'Alaska') that is unsorted. Outputting it with a `foreach` would output it in the unsorted fashion. Sorting/determining the order of associative arrays is **encouraged** by the PHP manual by it's implementation of [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) which *specifically calls out being useful for assoc arrays*.

Comment: I tried finding a duplicate, but could not find one either. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696330/associative-array-move-an-element-to-first-position) has a very relevant title, but is premised on the fact that elements are added to the array to be sorted - thus, justifying it's marked duplicate. This one does not use that premise and might be useful if an array is provided by a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

simplest way to do with below code

```
$arr = array(
'key1'=>'value1',
'key2'=>'value2',
'key3'=>'value3'
);

$lastvalue = end($arr);
$lastkey = key($arr);

$arr1 = array($lastkey=>$lastvalue);

array_pop($arr);

$arr1 = array_merge($arr1,$arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [key3] => value3
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

Comment: Quick and clean, move last to first element:
$element = array_pop( $array );
array_unshift( $array, $element );

Comment: array_unshift($arr, $last = array_pop($arr));

Comment: This never worked for me. Try this one: array_unshift($hoursArray,$hoursArray[sizeof($hoursArray)-1]);
array_pop($hoursArray);

Answer (score 16):

Just a matter of splicing it and merging it to the beginning

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);

$newArray = array_merge(array_splice($array, -1), $array);

var_dump($newArray);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["key3"]=>
  string(6) "value3"
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User the function `array_reverse()` to reverse the array,
Like :

```
<?php
$arr=array(
   'key1'=>'value1',
   'key2'=>'value2',
   'key3'=>'value3'
);
$reversed = array_reverse($arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($reversed);
?>
```

Comment: I dont have to reverse the complete array.

Comment: too much complexity for simple work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);

$count = 1;
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($count == 1)
        $first[$k] = $v;
    if ($count == count($array))
        $last[$k] = $v;

    $count++;
}

array_shift($array);
array_pop($array);
$final = array_merge($last, $array, $first);
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

first goto last item or array, use end(fastest one) for that purpose.Now fetch key,value then delete it and add to top.

```
$last_val = end($original_array);
$last_key = key($original_array);
unset($original_array[$key]);
$new_array = array($last_key => $last_val) + $original_array;
```