# Changing key name in array

Tags: php

I have an array called `$eduAdd` and I'm adding a string to the beginning of it like this:

```
array_unshift($eduAdd, $userId);
```

This is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [fieldId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [educationTitle] => Array
        (
            [0] => g
        )

    [educationDegree] => Array
        (
            [0] => g
        )

)
```

How can I rename `[0] => 3` to `['userId'] => 3`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783750/php-add-item-to-beginning-of-associative-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `array_unshift` just use `$eduAdd['userId'] = $userId` in the first place;

Comment: + But note that `$eduAdd['userId']` would not add it has the first element ...

Comment: I need `['userId'] => 3 ` as the first element

Comment: Oh... I missed that point though it seems pointless to me

Comment: @Musa - You're right, it's pointless. I just looked at the code again and it does not matter. I thought it did at first, but it will work at the end. Been a LONG 2 days ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be the first element (although pointless in an array), try using [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) -

```
$userId['userId'] = $userId
$eduAdd = array_merge($userId,$eduAdd);
```

phpfiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1m0-yfn