# Insertion at the beginning of array using Union Operator - new element is Overwriting the (previously) first element of the array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

The following SSCCE prints:

`Array ( [0] => FLAT [1] => A [2] => B [3] => C [4] => D [5] => E [6] => F [7] => G [8] => H [9] => I [10] => J )`

***What I wanted:***

What I wanted was to insert an element with a value of `"flat"` at the start of the array, i.e. I wanted `"flat"` to be inserted at index `0`, and the rest of the elements should move right by one position to give free position for the insertion at the beginning of the array.

So I tried to use the union operator. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783750/php-add-item-to-beginning-of-associative-array#answer-5783777)

***What I got:***

But what actually happened was that the first element of the array, **`"id"`**, was over-written/replaced by the newly inserted element.

**The question is that why is this happening, and what should I do to achieve what I need?**

```
$array = array(
  0 => "id",
  1 => "A",
  2 => "B",
  3 => "C",
  4 => "D",
  5 => "E",
  6 => "F",
  7 => "G",
  8 => "H",
  9 => "I",
  10 => "J"
);

$arrayNew = array("flat") + $array;

print_r($array_new);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual [Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, **the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored**.

Try `array_unshift()` to modify the array:

```
array_unshift($array, array("flat"));
```

Or `array_merge()`:

```
$arrayNew = array_merge(array("flat"), $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using array_merge()

```
$array = array(
  0 => "id",
  1 => "A",
  2 => "B",
  3 => "C",
  4 => "D",
  5 => "E",
  6 => "F",
  7 => "G",
  8 => "H",
  9 => "I",
  10 => "J"
);

$arrayNew = array_merge(array("flat"), $array);

print_r($arrayNew);
```

> Array ( [0] => flat [1] => id [2] => A [3] => B [4] => C [5] => D [6] => E [7] => F [8] => G [9] => H [10] => I [11] => J )

Answer (score 0):

use `array_unshift` which will add elements to the beginning of the array.

$arr=array( [0] => FLAT [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) => A [2] => B [3] => C [4] => D [5] => E [6] => F [7] => G [8] => H [9] => I [10] => J );

array_unshift($arr, "flat");

[php array_unshift manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)